# how to delete app file directories via programming while uninstalling the android app?

Tags: android

I have developed an app which uses cache file directory

> "mypackagename" and database directory
>
> "/data/data/com.mypackagename"

How can I delete these files programmatically while uninstalling the app?

Answer (score 0):

App storage is deleted automatically when uninstalled.  You don't have to write any code for that.

Comment: I have checked it. But the folders are still in the file explorer even if i uninstalled the app

Comment: Restart or refresh whatever tool you're using.